# how to dynamically render reactjs components from json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have some json data. 3 different objects. I would like to take the data from those objects and present it on the screen. basically each object has a name, summary and icon. so I'd like to go through all 3 of these objects and display on the screen each icon, name and summary. these objects are featured apps. they are displayed in a grid. each app has its own badge. the badge is in the AppBadgeHomePage.js file.

right now nothing is rendering. I get the h3 tag and that's it. there's a div class for "featured" but there is nothing below. it seems the `this.state.feat.map` is broken. or not working. or maybe it is and there's just nothing getting passed to the app badge. I call the featured apps grid in another file just fine. I'm just wondering if this is one of those cases where I'm too tired and have been staring at this for too long.

the json data looks like this. the icon and summary are in a customData object.

```
{
 name: appName,
 customData: {
     icon: iconURL,
     summary: summary
  }
 }
```

Marketplace.js

```
import AppBadgeHomePage from './AppBadgeHomePage';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class FeaturedGrid extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.getFeaturedApps = this.getFeaturedApps.bind(this);
        let name, summary, icon;
    }
    
    state = {
        feat: []
    }

    getFeaturedApps = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/apps/featured`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            this.setState({
                feat: responseJson.map(item => ({
                    name: item.name,
                    icon: item.customData.icon,
                    summary: item.customData.summary
                }))
            })
        })
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Featured Apps</h3>
                    <div className="featured">
                        {this.state.feat.map(featured => (
                            <AppBadgeHomePage 
                                name={featured.name}
                                icon={featured.customData.icon}
                                summary={featured.customData.summary}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

AppBadgeHomePage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class AppBadgeHomePage extends React.Component {
    
    render(){
        return (
            <a className="featured-grid-item-badge" href="www.google.com">
                <div className="featured-grid-item">
                    <img className="featured-appIcon" src={this.props.icon} />
                        <div>
                            <p className="featuredTitle">{this.props.name}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className="badgeSummary">{this.props.summary}</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `fetch` can reject on network errors, so you should include a `.catch` to handle promise rejections and thrown errors. Also, you need to first check `response.ok` *before* further accessing into the response object. See [Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful). Adding some "sad path" handling may help you find why `this.state.feat` remains an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mapping for feat ,feat supposed to be an array

Try this :-

```
 getFeaturedApps = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/apps/featured`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
            feat: responseJson
            }))
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: the idea is that all the featured apps are in the feat array. I would pull the data from there.

also I made the edits you suggested and still there is no <AppBadgeHomePage> or any of the data inside of there

Comment: can you check console.log(this.state.feat) if it return anything

Comment: it returns empty

Comment: .then(response => console.log(response)) are you getting response the way you expected?

Comment: .then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => console.log(responseJson));

Comment: First of all check if your endpoint returns the required JSON. After it is confirmed then try this `this.setState({...this.state, feat: responseJson});`

Comment: @ImranKhan Class-based component's `this.setState` shallow merges state updates, so spreading in current state isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to console.log(this.state.feed) under render method to see if the feed array is not blank always.

If its blank then I would suggest you to call the the API in componentDidMount() method.

If its not blank then you would notice that the feed state has the object which you have already set it to your desired key value pair so there is no need to this:

```
<AppBadgeHomePage 
   name={featured.name}
   icon={featured.customData.icon}
   summary={featured.customData.summary}
/>
```

rather do this:

```
<AppBadgeHomePage 
   name={featured.name}
   icon={featured.icon}
   summary={featured.summary}
/>
```

To sum it up, if the child component is not being rendered than the array must be blank all the way. And if the child component is being rendered and the value is not showing up then the key being called is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the react docs:

[constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in the
> constructor. For those use cases, use `componentDidMount()` instead.

1. The data fetch should be dispatched from `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.
2. Don't mix using the `constructor` ***and*** initializing state in
   the class body.
3. `getFeaturedApps` is an arrow function, so there is no need to bind `this` to it in the constructor.
4. You should check for successful `fetch` in the promise chain. You should also handle promise rejections and other thrown errors from the returned promise chain.
5. When mapping `this.state.feat` you incorrectly try to access what was the original nested values, but you flattened the feature element when it was mapped in the fetch response handling.

Code:

```
class FeaturedGrid extends React.Component {
  state = {
    feat: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFeaturedApps();
  }

  getFeaturedApps = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/apps/featured`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Response not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          feat: responseJson.map((item) => ({
            name: item.name,
            icon: item.customData.icon,
            summary: item.customData.summary
          }))
        });
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Featured Apps</h3>
        <div className="featured">
          {this.state.feat.map((featured) => (
            <AppBadgeHomePage
              name={featured.name}
              icon={featured.icon}
              summary={featured.summary}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```